# How to find out opened readers in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have some IndexReaders (for different commits) and a single IndexWriter opened. I index some documents, and in the end only one reader should be opened and the old ones should be closed. The readers should be closed, but when I restart the system(meaning I restart the IndexWriter), actually the size of the index in disk shrinks at least by half, meaning that probably some readers were still opened. Is there any way to figure out the readers per commit that are still in use in a certain moment?

Answer (score 0):

At a time we re-factored out application to use IndexSearcher (through SearchManager), exactly for that reason: IndexReaders have such a twisted approach to concurrency & resource cleanup, that we found it impossible to manage (us and many others, apparently - even before SearchManager was added to the API its approach was recommended in "Lucene in Action" )
http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/09/lucenes-searchermanager-simplifies.html

Comment: Hi Pelit, thank you very much for the answer. My problem is that I cache information for each of the segments, and I create a MultiReader out of each SegmentReeader. I close the segments and the multireader when I dont use the reader anymore, but on the management of that, it looks like I have an error!

Comment: So sorry, I have no insights on that - apologies